# separate each words in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I had an value in database like "demo text" . I want to display this content from the db in the view page as

[image: demo text]

Html code that i am using is like this  `<h2>Demo<span>Text</span></h2>` , is there any solution for seperate each words and use one for h2 and other for span. I am using php codeigniter for the project , I don't know that whether the way i explained my problem is correct or not .

Comment: If you're text is always made up of two words you can use `explode` with a space, so you'll get an array of two words !

Comment: explode(" ","demo text");

Comment: in your db you have `<h2>Demo<span>Text</span></h2>`? or you have `demo text`

Comment: No the text is not always made up of two words

Comment: @madalin I have " demo text " in db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can so it with explode

if you have stored at least 2 words with space. try following

```
$demo ="demo text";
$arr = explode(" ",$demo);
$str = "<h2>".$arr[0]."<span>".$arr[1]."</span></h2>";
echo $str;
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/S7Nfv)

**EDIT**

If you have more words and want to split first word only you can pass limit parameter in explode

```
$demo ="Pligrimage to Marian Shrines";
$arr = explode(" ",$demo,2);
$str = "<h2>".$arr[0]."<span>".$arr[1]."</span></h2>";
echo $str;
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/rHZBr)

Comment: I already done this using explode function but some time the data may be bore than 2 words.

Comment: what will be your out put when data is more than 2 words

Comment: while using two words it is ok but while it is three then "undefined offset" error.

Comment: I use "Pligrimage to Marian Shrines" now it displays only "Pilgrimage to" there is no marian shrines

Comment: So you need `<h2>Pligrimage <span> to Marian Shrines</span></h2>` as ouput?

Comment: Yes absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this!

```
$your_string = "Hello Houston! We have a problem!";
$my_array = explode(" ",trim($your_string));
$output = "<h2>";

foreach($my_array as $a_word){
    if ($a_word === reset($my_array))
        $output .= $a_word;
    else
        $output .= " <span>". $a_word . "</span>";
}

$output .= "</h2>";

print $output;
```